# Values based on current date time ( current date time from an outer table )

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

currently I've got data that i'm trying to pull based on the latest date and time. The date time is listed in an outer table that is being brought together from a join

```
Date_Local                 Name     Value
2019-08-13 10:30:54.377    Ted       20
2019-08-13 10:30:54.377    Jake      50
2019-08-12 09:10:55.377     Ben      30
```

Result:-

Expected result is to pull on Ted and Jake data rows.

Comment: OK, so what's your question? What's stopping you from doing what you want to do? Also, in case no one else has told you, SQL Server 2008(R2) is completely out of support now and it's highly recommended you upgrade as soon as you can.

Comment: @Larnu In which position should I place. Inner Join Table1 On Table.ID = Table 1.ID AND Table1.Date_Local =  (Select max(table1.date_Local) from table1). Currently I've got this placed within a join. Is this appropriate for join or does this belong in where clause?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
SELECT T.Date_Local,T.Name,T.value
FROM tbladata T
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Date_Local ORDER BY Date_Local) as rowNum,
       Name,
       Value,
       Date_Local
FROM tblaData
) AS sub ON(T.Date_Local=sub.Date_Local)
WHERE sub.rowNum>1
```

Comment: Take the time to explain your answer to the OP.